# VBA to Oracle 10g Error

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

Greetings..

I'm very new to Oracle but have knowledge in Sql.

i'm trying to connect external Oracle DB from VBA - Excel below is the code..

```
 Function ORAQUERY(strHost As String, strDatabase As String, strSQL As String,
 strUser As String, strPassword As String)
 Dim strConOracle, oConOracle, oRsOracle
 Dim StrResult As String
 StrResult = ""
 strConOracle = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
 "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=207.169.236.29)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEDWRP01.DE.EDS.COM))); uid=" & strUser & " ;pwd=" & strPassword & ";"
 Set oConOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set oRsOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 oConOracle.Open strConOracle
 End Function
```

while trying to run the above code i'm getting below error ..

**[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12154:TNS:Cound not resolve the connect identifier specified**

I have installed oracle 10g and i can able to connect the database via **Oracle SQL* Plus** ..

[image]

Please help me .Thanks for help in advance ..

Comment: Have you tried setting up a tnsnames entry explicitly, and created a DSN and tested it from the ODBC admin panel?  I would try that first to rule out an ODBC setup issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... Could you please let me know how do i do that ? new to this .. :( Please

Comment: Please check http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/. Look for "Microsoft ODBC" in this page for different ways to connect, depending on the method you want.

Comment: Sorry, too much effort.  Do you even have the MS Oracle odbc driver installed?

Comment: Please show your SQL*Plus command line or login information.

Comment: See what drivers are installed on your machine.  What OS version are you running?  Run "ODBC" from the start/run prompt to find the ODBC admin panel, then click on the Drivers tab to see which ODBC drivers are installed.

Comment: OS : windows 7 64 bit , drivers installed :Sql server and sql server native client 10.0 .                                                  Sql * plus requires user name,password and host name information ..

Comment: you can also refer attached image ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a live code that I use:

```
Dim oCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
oCon.ConnectionString = "DSN=YOUR_DNS;UID=YOUR_USERNAME;PWD=YOUR_PASSWORD;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=YOUR_WSID"
oCon.Open
Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
oRS.ActiveConnection = oCon

'Loop through Oracle
    oRS.Source = "select DATA from TABEL;"
    oRS.Open

        Do While Not oRS.EOF
            Debug.Print oRS.Fields("DATA").Value
            oRS.MoveNext
        Loop

    oRS.Close

oCon.Close


If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
If Not oCon Is Nothing Then Set oCon = Nothing
```

Connect to Oracle - remember to activate Tools->References->"Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"